# norm of a variant of Fejer 's kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $K_N$ the Fejer's kernel on $\mathbb{T}$. Let $l$ be a positive integer. Let $Q$ the function defined by
$$
Q(t)=K_N(lt).
$$
In Hewitt/Ross "Abstract Harmonic Analysis 2" page 438, I can read that if $1<p<2$ we have
$$
||Q||_{L_p}=||K_N||_{L_p}.
$$
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have a function $f$ on $\mathbb{T}$ and an integer $k$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(kt)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$
The integral on the right is just $k$ copies of the integral on the left compressed $k$ times (so each copy has $1/k$ times the integral on the left).

$\hspace{5mm}$
[image]
[image]